# checkout files simultaneously in perforce

Tags: cvs, perforce

In CVS we cant check out the files simultaneously. 
Can anybody tell ....whether in perforce can we checkout files simultaneously?

And i heard about locks on the files.
Before merging the file do we need to have a lock on them in perforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "simultaneously" you mean "more than one person can checkout the same file in parallel". Yes, that's possible.
Regarding locks: You `can` lock a file (see [the manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/cmdref/lock.html)), but you don't need to.
And yes, the ones who want to submit after the first person submitted have to resolve (and possibly merge) the changes and can then submit.

Comment: is it possible to checkin the same file at a time?If yes how

Comment: @sap: It is impossible, as they need to go to the same server.  The server would get to one of the submissions first, and that one would be considered the first change made, with the next one being rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding locks:

- You don't need a lock on files before submitting them.
- A file can be manually locked and unlocked if you want to restrict changes from happening during a portion of time.
- A file can't be manually locked if someone else has already checked the file out (I believe), except possibly by admin override.
- You can make certain file types automatically lock when checked out (called exclusive checkout), where it makes sense to do so.  For example, most binary image formats don't merge well, so those are usually made exclusive checkout to prevent two different people from modifying the image at the same time.